# Can't figure out gradient descent linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression, gradient, gradient-descent

I'm currently working on gradient descent projects.

I chose nba stats as my data so I downloaded 3Pts data and pts data from basketball reference and I have successfully plotted a scatter plot. However, the result does not seem right.

My scatter plot is going towards right-upside (since more 3points made generally means more points scored, so it makes sense)

But my gradient descent line is going to left-upside, I don't know what's wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/jeehw/Documents/FG3M_PTS_2021.csv')


X = data.iloc[:,1]
Y = data.iloc[:,2]

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.xlabel('FG3M')                                  
plt.ylabel('PTS')
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()

m = 0
c = 0

L = 0.001
epochs = 200

n = float(len(X))

for i in range(len(X)):
Y_pred = m*X + c
m_Grad = (1/n) * sum(X * (Y_pred - Y))
c_Grad = (1/n) * sum(Y_pred - Y)


m = m - L* m_Grad
c = c - L* c_Grad

Y_pred = m*X + c

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.scatter(X, Y_pred)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the data publicly available?  It is difficult to help without the data

Comment: I think OP needs to clarify the indentation first. That for loop is useless as it is

Comment: partly yes. actually you can download from basketball reference. go to 2021 nba season player stats and order players in 3PM numbers (most 3pm to least) I modified the table (it has a function on top of table) I only left 3PM and PTS and Names. then i donwloaded it in CSV file. I don't know how to attatch file here..... i I can i would attatch here

Comment: what do you mean by OP and indentation? I am really really new to this field so Im very lost. could you clarify little further? thank you!

Comment: OP = original poster; and your for loop is not indented. Anything within your loop needs to be indented (basic python syntax)

Comment: part of this code doesn't make sense. What is n for?  you have Y_pred in there twice. Are you simply trying to use linear regression to predict? In that case, you need to split your data into training and test data. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things in this code don't really make sense. Are you trying to do the regression from scratch? Because you do import scikit learn but never apply it. You can refer to this link on how to use scikit learn regression [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-ols-py). I would also consider playing around with other algorithms too.

I believe this is what you are trying to do here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


#data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/jeehw/Documents/FG3M_PTS_2021.csv')
raw_data = pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_totals.html')[0]
raw_data  = raw_data[raw_data['Rk'].ne('Rk')]

data = raw_data[['Player','3P','PTS']]
data[['3P','PTS']] = data[['3P','PTS']].astype(int)

X = data.iloc[:]['3P'].values
y = data.iloc[:]['PTS'].values

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.xlabel('FG3M')                                  
plt.ylabel('PTS')
plt.scatter(X,y)

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(X), max(X)+1, 20))
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1, 100))
plt.show()


# Split data into test and Train
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X_train.reshape(-1, 1), y_train)

# Make predictions using the testing set
y_pred = regr.predict(X_test.reshape(-1, 1))



# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
# The mean squared error
print('Mean squared error: %.2f'
      % mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
# The coefficient of determination: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Coefficient of determination: %.2f'
      % r2_score(y_test, y_pred))

# Plot outputs
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color='red', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(X_test), max(X_test)+1, 20))
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y_pred), max(y_pred)+1, 100))

plt.xlabel('FG3M')                                  
plt.ylabel('PTS')

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

There is some noise in there. You have a lot of players who score a lot of points, who NEVER shoot a 3pt, let alone make one. So I would consider do a good amount of data cleaning first (maybe take only players who've had at least 50 3 point attempts? Or Get rid of Centers? Also if a player changes teams, they may be in the dataset a few times with thier totals for each team, so there is some redundancy in there...but I'm not going to take the time to clean it since it's beyond the scope of the question). I would also test out other machine learning algorithms. But the code above should at least get you going and playing around. Have fun!

Comment: oh my god.... Thank you so so so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. And yes! I used your rest of the code but replaced data with my CSV file. I've filtered players by only colllecting data from players with at least 100 FG3M this season. so i got 106 players. Thank you so so much again. Hopefully I become better at coding soon and wanna help others like you!

Comment: can i just ask one question? so i understand the train/test MSE. but what does 

(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

random state 42 and test size 0.2 mean?

Comment: test size=.20 means the training and test data sets are split into 80% and 20%. Rule of thumb is you usually want to have about 70-80% training. So you could change test_set=.3

Comment: The random state is set so that when you do the split again, it gives you same split. you can set it to any old number. But lets say for example you want to test 2 different parameters in the logistic regression to see if changing it will improve the performance/predictions. You'll want to try it on the same training and test sets otherwise you don't know if the difference in the 2 performances is infact the parameter change, or if it was just by chance you got a better training split. So by setting a random_state, you essentially recreate the same split each time.